# Find number of page requests in asp .net

Tags: asp.net, .net, iis, request

What would be the most efficient way (ie. less intrusive) to keep track of all page requests within an asp .net application? Is there a way to record the number of requests at the Application Pool level in IIS?

Comment: This is extremely broad. What did you find by typing "IIS request logging" into your favorite web search engine and what parts of that didn't you understand?

Comment: Have you tried Google Analytics? What kind of information are you looking for?

Comment: There are also a number of ASP.NET performance counters.

Comment: You could add to a count in [Application_BeginRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpapplication.beginrequest(v=vs.110).aspx), storing the result in an Application variable.

Comment: I guess IIS Request Logging is the less intrusive way. I'm only looking at crude numbers of page accesses and their times. If I store a vble in Application_BeginRequest then that would need to be stored somewhere, thus impacting performance, so I think a better choice would be to use Advanced Logging for IIS